# Index n-dimensional array with vector and a blank/dummy index

Tags: r

How do you index a n dimensional array in R using a vector, but leaving eg one index blank/dummy index? Here is an example.

```
m <- array(1:9, c(3,3,3)) 
m[,c(1,2)]
#Error in m[, c(1, 2)] : incorrect number of dimensions
m[,1,2]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

I want

```
m[,c(1,2)]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

This works with a matrix (https://rspatial.org/intr/4-indexing.html)

```
m <- matrix(1:9, nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(m) <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
m

m[, c('a', 'c')]
##      a c
## [1,] 1 3
## [2,] 4 6
## [3,] 7 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to construct a `matrix`

```
ind <-  do.call(cbind, c(list(seq(dim(m)[1])), as.list(c(1, 2))))
m[ind]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

---

Or as @user20650 commented

```
do.call("[", c(list(m), TRUE, 1, 2))
```